# blitTileFromQueue ERROR in android

Tags: android

I am using SocialAuth sdk for implementing social media class . All code is ok . Let I have get the following screen

[image]

But when I am trying to input username the screen looks like as following :

[image]

In the logcat, I am getting the following exception .

```
01-16 12:04:27.764: E/TransferQueue(1046): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 175, srcTexId 172, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
    01-16 12:04:27.944: E/GLUtils(1046): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
    01-16 12:04:27.944: E/TransferQueue(1046): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 174, srcTexId 172, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
    01-16 12:04:28.064: E/GLUtils(1046): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
    01-16 12:04:28.064: E/TransferQueue(1046): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 175, srcTexId 172, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
    01-16 12:04:28.244: E/GLUtils(1046): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
    01-16 12:04:28.254: E/TransferQueue(1046): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 176, srcTexId 172, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
    01-16 12:04:28.384: E/GLUtils(1046): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
    01-16 12:04:28.384: E/TransferQueue(1046): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 177, srcTexId 172, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
    01-16 12:07:52.644: D/dalvikvm(1046): GC_CONCURRENT freed 155K, 9% free 3634K/3988K, paused 7ms+105ms, total 225ms
    01-16 12:07:52.913: E/GLUtils(1046): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
    01-16 12:07:52.913: E/TransferQueue(1046): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 174, srcTexId 172, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
    01-16 12:07:53.043: E/GLUtils(1046): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
    01-16 12:07:53.043: E/TransferQueue(1046): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 176, srcTexId 172, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
    01-16 12:07:53.344: E/GLUtils(1046): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
    01-16 12:07:53.344: E/TransferQueue(1046): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 177, srcTexId 172, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
    01-16 12:07:53.953: E/GLUtils(1046): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
    01-16 12:07:53.953: E/TransferQueue(1046): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 174, srcTexId 172, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
    01-16 12:07:54.214: E/GLUtils(1046): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
    01-16 12:07:54.223: E/TransferQueue(1046): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 177, srcTexId 172, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
    01-16 12:07:54.554: E/GLUtils(1046): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
    01-16 12:07:55.093: E/GLUtils(1046): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
    01-16 12:07:55.093: E/TransferQueue(1046): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 177, srcTexId 172, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
    01-16 12:07:55.734: E/GLUtils(1046): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
    01-16 12:07:55.734: E/TransferQueue(1046): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 174, srcTexId 172, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
    01-16 12:07:56.154: E/GLUtils(1046): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
    01-16 12:07:56.154: E/TransferQueue(1046): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 177, srcTexId 172, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
    01-16 12:07:56.694: E/GLUtils(1046): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
    01-16 12:07:56.694: E/TransferQueue(1046): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 174, srcTexId 172, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
    01-16 12:07:57.224: E/GLUtils(1046): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
    01-16 12:07:57.224: E/TransferQueue(1046): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 177, srcTexId 172, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
    01-16 12:07:57.863: E/GLUtils(1046): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
    01-16 12:07:57.863: E/TransferQueue(1046): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 174, srcTexId 172, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
    01-16 12:07:58.233: E/GLUtils(1046): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
    01-16 12:07:58.233: E/TransferQueue(1046): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 177, srcTexId 172, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
    01-16 12:07:58.943: E/GLUtils(1046): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
    01-16 12:07:58.954: E/TransferQueue(1046): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 174, srcTexId 172, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
    01-16 12:07:59.284: E/GLUtils(1046): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
    01-16 12:07:59.284: E/TransferQueue(1046): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 177, srcTexId 172, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
    01-16 12:07:59.834: E/GLUtils(1046): GL ERROR - after At the end of blitTileFromQueue()() glError (0x501)
    01-16 12:07:59.834: E/TransferQueue(1046): blitTileFromQueue ERROR: fboId 1, destTexId 174, srcTexId 172, textureWidth 256, textureHeight 256
```

I have run the code in my friends emulator . There it is ok . Can you tell me what is the possible error ?